# Redirecting doesn't work after fetch post method with react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect to root path `/` after data is successfully posted to an api (with status 200), so I write as following

```
// post method fetch

.. then(res => {
     if (res.status === 200) {
         return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
              }}
            ></Redirect>
          );
      }
  })
```

But this doesn't do any redirect and doesn't show any error, Am I putting `Redirect` in wrong position or What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Redirect you can use useHistory you can import it like :-

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

and in place of Redirect you can put it like:-

```
.. then(res => {
     if (res.status === 200) {
         return (
            history.replace('/')
          );
      }
  })
```

but first you need to const history like:-

```
const history = useHistory();
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I thought the only way to redirect to page is by `Redirect`, I will look more into `useHistory` later